# Mplayer2 -udp-master

Tags: mplayer

I am in confuse to use `mplayer` or `mplayer2` package from Ubuntu. Both has the one I need, but lack another features, which also needed.

`mplayer` is great, I was using it until i got an error with `*.dat` video file and the the errors are

```
Requested audio codec family [mpg123] (afm=mpg123) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
Unknown/missing audio format -> no sound
ADecoder init failed :(
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
Unknown/missing audio format -> no sound
ADecoder init failed :(
Requested audio codec family [mad] (afm=libmad) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Opening audio decoder: [hwmpa] MPEG audio pass-through (fake decoder)
Cannot sync MPA frame: 0
ADecoder init failed :(
ADecoder init failed :(
Opening audio decoder: [spdif] libavformat/spdifenc audio pass-through decoder.
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, mpeg2, 768.0 kbit/50.00% (ratio: 96000->192000)
Selected audio codec: [spdifmpa] afm: spdif (libavformat/spdifenc MPEG AUDIO BC pass-through decoder)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
[format] Sample format big-endian MPEG-2 not yet supported 
[libaf] Reinitialization did not work, audio filter 'format' returned error code -2
[libaf] Unable to setup filter system can not meet sound-card demands, please send a bug report. 
Couldn't find matching filter/ao format!
Audio: no sound
```

So, i tried to move to `mplayer2`, playing the same file. ***Audio comes out***, working. But then, i realize, `mplayer2` doesn't have something that i need,

```
Unknown option on the command line: --udp-master
MPlayer2 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
```

So, the questions are

1. How to enable mpg123 to `mplayer` ?
2. Or, how to enable udp for sync'ed network playback in `mplayer2` ?

I tried downloaded mplayer 1.3 from its website, and compiled. But more and more error shows up, the video not even displaying,

3. What is `configure` options used on the `mplayer` package from ubuntu, I'm thinking of using the very-same options, adding `mpg123` at compilation.

Thank you.

Comment: This guide may be helpful: http://www.andrews-corner.org/ubuntu/mplayer.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, I followed the guide, with additional `apt-get install libmpg123-dev`, and compile mplayer with `--enable-mpg123`, but final step of the guide show error, `ad_mpg123.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `mpg123_exit'` I am using 14.04 64bit though. Limbpg123 version, `libmpg123-dev 1.16.0-1ubuntu1`

Comment: It might sound counter-intuitive but you should omit `--enable-mpg123` and simply allow the MPlayer ./configure process to find the `-dev` file itself.

Comment: compile succeded (using the guide), but now, it also doesn't have `--udp-master` options. The result of compiled version is `MPlayer SVN-r37893-4.8 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team`

Comment: OK, it was my bad. it should `-udp-master` instead of `--udp-master`. Solved for the compilation process.

Comment: And now your issue is resolved? Or does the whole issue hinge on a bad command line :)

Comment: Well, result is still a failure. even though the binary is now recognize mpg123, but saying `mpg123 failed to reopen stream: Error reading the stream. (code 18)`